# Is the alternate version of Tashahhud valid or a Bidah?

Tags: salat, tashahhud

In Tashahhud, Muslims say:

> ٱلتَّحِيَّاتُ لِلَّٰهِ وَٱلصَّلَوَاتُ وَٱلطَّيِّبَاتُ، ٱلسَّلَامُ
> عَلَيْكَ أَيُّهَا ٱلنَّبِيُّ وَرَحْمَةُ ٱللَّٰهِ وَبَرَكَاتُهُ

But recently, I've found out, there are some Muslims who pray like so:

> التَّحِيَّاتُ لِلَّهِ وَالصَّلَوَاتُ وَالطَّيِّبَاتُ السَّلَامُ عَلَى
> النَّبِيُّ وَرَحْمَةُ اللَّهِ وَبَرَكَاتُهُ

Now, I am aware of the saying in which the 2nd supplication is mentioned where a companion is saying (paraphrasing):

> When Prophet was alive, we used to pray the 1st supplication and when
> he died, we changed it to the 2nd supplication.

According to my knowledge, none of the 4 Imams has used the 2nd supplication & it was neither taught by the Prophet himself! Also, I don't think any big scholar like Nawawi, Ibn Hajar etc has allowed the 2nd supplication!

### Question:

Is there anyone before 18th century who has used the saying of the companion (above) as a Hujja to use 2nd supplication in prayer? Anyone from the Salaf? Or any big scholar? If so, please provide authentic evidence...

Thanks.

Comment: You yourself showed that a companion said it can be used (who was obviously before the 18th century). So, what do you mean to ask? If one of the 4 schools said it?

Comment: @TheZ I've clarified the question. It should be clear now

Comment: Do you know there are multiple versions of that tashahhud anyway? Even not counting this difference of عَلَيْكَ أَيُّهَا ٱلنَّبِيُّ vs. عَلَى النَّبِيُّ. The phrasing of the question makes it seem like you think there's only one wording for the whole thing. The one you have quoted is the tashahhud narrated by Ibn Masood (RA), and it is preferred by the Hanafis and Hanbalis.

Comment: @TheZ You are talking about something else

Comment: So, you wish for only a discussion of this phrase عَلَى النَّبِيُّ?